How to point Sphinx towards a custom theme
Note: I have asked this question before but deleted it because I gave up on the project, but now I actually need to find out how.
I'm trying to make a Sphinx theme, but I can't get Sphinx to detect my theme. My folder structure looks something like this:
.
docs
   conf.py
   makefile
   make.bat
   index.md
custom_theme
   theme.toml
   layout.html

And I will point the theme in my conf.py file as such:
html_theme = 'custom_theme'

However, Sphinx will return an error with the folowing:
Theme error:
no theme named 'custom_theme' found (missing theme.toml?)
Sphinx exited with exit code: 2

How do I get Sphinx to build the Documentation with my custom theme?
Additional Context:
I use Myst-Parser because I prefer markdown over reStructuredText, and I also use Sphinx Autobuild. As per the Sphinx Autobuild documentation, I ran sphinx-autobuild -a docs docs/_build/html --watch custom_theme as apprently with this command, Sphinx  can detect the custom theme.
Let me know if you need more context, any and all help is appreciated. Thanks.

FYI, I've used Sphinx Theme Builder to develop Plone Sphinx Theme. I use MyST.

Here is how I would do it:

Put the theme in a _themes folder inside the docs folder.
In conf.py, add html_theme_path = ['_themes'] (in addition to html_theme = 'custom_theme' that you already have).

Example: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/doc/conf.py#L36

It is also possible to put custom_theme directly in docs and use html_theme_path = ["."]. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/theming.html#using-a-theme.
